# Outlook rest api returning 503

Tags: office365api, outlook-restapi

I've recently started getting 503 errors from the Outlook REST API when calling: https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me to obtain info about the current user's email address.

It return a 503 status code with HTML that contains the oh so helpful message "Sorry, we can't get that information right now. Please try again later."

I would think it is a temporary failure except it seems to persist for a given user and isn't just a temporary thing.

Anyone else see anything similar before or have any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the response headers?